# CSS Div Block re-arranging for multiple screens

Tags: html, css

So what I'm trying to do is design a page that has two sidebars and a main article area. As it shrinks down for tablet or phone use though, I want the two sidebars to move so they are stacked vertically beside the main area at first, and then eventually both move below it. The Problem I am having is I can't get them to re-order correctly upon doing so.

The three sections on the left (desktop/tablet/phone) is how I want it. The pages on the right are how it's appearing now. Basically I need 5 to move up under 4, and 3 to move beside 4/5 for tablet view, and then 4 to move down under 3 for phone view.

I hope that makes sense? I'm using Dreamweaver if it helps/matters. Thanks!

[Clicky to see what I mean!](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/7779/wantedzz.png)

Comment: hard to tell what is wrong with it without the code.  Could you post some code?  Also, are you using CSS media queries?

Comment: I'm just using what Dreamweaver put out when I selected Fluid Grid Layouts. Trying to post the code, but it's way too long

Answer (score 0):

It can be done **if** certain heights are known.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/Pt7sS/

The height of `#contentWrap` and `#sideRight` need to be known to make this work. If these are not known, you can fetch the heights through jQuery.

```
html, body, #header1, #header2, #contentWrap {
    width: 100%
}

#header1 {
    background: red;
    height: 50px
}

#header2 {
    background: green;
    height: 40px
}

#sideLeft, #main, #sideRight {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    height: 200px
}

#sideLeft, #sideRight {
    width: 20%;
    background: #333
}

#main {
    background: grey;
    width: 60%
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #main {
        float: right;
        width: 65%
    }

    #sideRight {
        clear: left
    }

    #sideRight, #sideLeft {
        width: 35%;
        height: 100px
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    #sideLeft, #main, #sideRight {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute
    }

    #contentWrap {
        position: relative;
        height: 400px
    }

    #main {
        top: 0
    }

    #sideLeft {
        bottom: 100px
    }

    #sideRight {
        bottom: 0
    }
}
​
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fRDz0VfO5HjYmcRAvTjZyFwGtpub7UDi8EBjrLTW8N8/edit Here's the code it put out.

Comment: And? I gave you the code that fixes it. I'm not going to implement it. We're not here to do jobs for people, but we are here to give advice and help.

Comment: Sorry, Joseph asked me for the code up above you. Perfectly understandable. My HTML knowledge is quite outdated, so I'm not exactly sure how to begin using jQuery to accomplish that. I'd never seen it before till I googled it after you mentioned it.